# Python Regex Match failed

Tags: python, regex

This passed on https://regex101.com/ without any issues. Did I miss anything? The entire string is in one line.

```
def get_title_and_content(html):
  html = """<!DOCTYPE html>     <html>       <head>       <title>Change delivery date with Deliv</title>       </head>       <body>       <div class="gkms web">The delivery date can be changed up until the package is assigned to a driver.</div>       </body>     </html>  """
  title_pattern = re.compile(r'<title>(.*?)</title>(.*)')
  match = title_pattern.match(html)
  if match:
    print('successfully extract title and answer')
      return match.groups()[0].strip(), match.groups()[1].strip()
    else:
      print('unable to extract title or answer')
```

Comment: Replace 'match = title_pattern.match(html)' with 'match = title_pattern.search(html)' Maybe?

Comment: Interesting! It works. Why does that matter?

Comment: I would not recommend parsing ***HTML*** with *Regex**, maybe take a look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). On a small scale it might not be too bad..... but on anything more than what you have above I would recommend finding another tool for HTML.

Comment: @Yang Because [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) only matches from the beginning of the provided string. If you want to get matches anywhere on the text (such as your specific use case), you need to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search). Refer to [search() vs. match()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) for more information.

Comment: Or change your regexp to `r'.*<title>(.*?)</title>(.*)'`

Comment: You could also use .findall() which i think returns a list

Comment: To follow up on what @PixelEinstein said: using `BeautifulSoup`, this whole thing (including parsing the answer out of that mess, of tags which includes part of the head and all of the body, which I assume you were planning to get to once you finished this part?) is `return soup.title.text, soup.div.text`.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are correct, re.match() searches from the beginning. That being said, insert a .* into your regex to search from the beginning:

```
title_pattern = re.compile(r'.*<title>(.*?)</title>(.*)')
```

Answer (score 0):

In a summary of the comments:

`title_pattern.search(html)` Should be used instead of `title_pattern.match(html)`

As the search function will search anywhere in the provided string instead of just from the beginning. `match = title_pattern.findall(html)` could be used similarly but would return a list of items instead of just one.

Also as mentioned using `BeautifulSoup` would pay of more in the long run as Regular Expression is not properly suited for searching HTML